# How to create dynamically disable a single check box of checkboxlist in YII

Tags: php, dynamic, yii, checkboxlist

In a form, I have checkboxlist which has two check box (Male and Female)
User can select both of them or any of them. And values are getting save in DB.

When we populate it from DB then I want to do like if male was selected then it should select Male checkbox and disable the Female checkbox or vice versa.

The code in my View file is:

```
<?php if(isset($model['gender'])){
      $data = $model['gender'];
      if (isset($data)) {
        if($data == 0)
             $htmlOptions = array(
                           '0' => array('label'=>'MALE'),
                           '1' => array('disabled'=>'disabled','label'=>'FEMALE'),);
        }
        if($data == 1){
             $htmlOptions = array(
                           '0' => array('disabled'=>'disabled','label'=>'MALE', ),
                           '1' => array('label'=>'FEMALE'),);
        }
     }     
     echo $form->checkBoxList($model, 'gender', $htmlOptions); ?>
```

Problem is when I am populating it is selecting the one,I selected while saving but not disabling the other one.

Answer (score -1):

For this you have to use javascript because there is no way you can handle it only with PHP. Now I don't know that much JS, but the steps are easy:

1. Get the checkbox id's
2. check which one is selected
3. disable the other one with innerHTML in JS.

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_disabled.asp) you have an example on how you disable checkboxes in JS

Just so you know, the JS  should be placed inside the view.

Comment: It is possible with PHP.... there are so many examples in net. But what I am trying is not working here.

Comment: Try the above... It's php independent and Yii independent. It is a workaround but it works